# Eloquent ORM laravel 5 Get Array of ids

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, model

I'm using Eloquent ORM laravel 5.1, and I want to return an array of ids greater than 0, my model is called `test`.

I have tried :

```
$test=test::select('id')->where('id' ,'>' ,0)->get()->toarray();
```

It returns :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 ) )
```

But I want the result to be in simple array like this:

```
Array ( 1,2 )
```

Answer (score 282, accepted):

```
test::where('id' ,'>' ,0)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

**NOTE:**
If you need a **string**, for example in a **blade**, you can use function without the **toArray()** part, like:

```
test::where('id' ,'>' ,0)->pluck('id');
```

**UPDATE:** For versions < 5.2

You could use **`lists()`** :

```
test::where('id' ,'>' ,0)->lists('id')->toArray();
```

**NOTE :** Better if you define your models in `Studly Case` format, e.g `Test`.

---

You could also use **[`get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-get)** :

```
test::where('id' ,'>' ,0)->get('id');
```

---

Comment: with pluck('id') array is array('0'=>12, '1'=>14) and etc, when used in WhereIn('id', $array), it selects not by id, but by array key, so by 0,1...

Comment: `toArray()` should return an array like `[12,14]`

Comment: oh yes, you are right, I was debugging via Debugbar ant print_r, and both of them showed array values with keys, but there are no keys. Thank you!

Comment: We're stuck on 4.2 for one project, so I appreciate keeping the ->lists('id') reference. Although that generated an array directly, didn't need to ->toArray it.

Answer (score 35):

From a `Collection`, another way you could do it would be:

```
$collection->pluck('id')->toArray()
```

This will return an indexed array, perfectly usable by laravel in a `whereIn()` query, for instance.

Comment: Used for Drop Down list as well.

Comment: To get the collection to pluck from from model `\YourModel::all(['id'])` ... `->pluck...` (with specifying just the ID column you don't load all data to model)

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer to that is the method `lists`, it's very simple like this:

```
$test=test::select('id')->where('id' ,'>' ,0)->lists('id');
```

Regards!

Comment: How would you get the related id's list in array through a many to many relationship??

Comment: Maybe you can use DB class, example: DB::table('name_of_table')->where('condition')->lists('id');

Answer (score 6):

You can use `all()` method instead of `toArray()` method (see more: [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck)):

```
test::where('id' ,'>' ,0)->pluck('id')->all(); //returns array
```

If you need a `string`, you can use without `toArray()` attachment:

```
test::where('id' ,'>' ,0)->pluck('id'); //returns string
```

Answer (score 6):

Just an extra info, if you are using `DB`:

```
DB::table('test')->where('id', '>', 0)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

And if using Eloquent model:

```
test::where('id', '>', 0)->lists('id')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to get an array with the model IDs ***from a collection***:

```
$test = test::select('id')->where('id' ,'>' ,0)->get('id')->modelKeys();
```

*Available since Laravel 5.5:* https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_modelKeys

Comment: As for Laravel 8: `... ->get()->modelKeys()`

Comment: ->get('id')->modelKeys();
- no need, it's enough
->->get()->model Keys();

Answer (score 5):

read about the lists() method

```
$test=test::select('id')->where('id' ,'>' ,0)->lists('id')->toArray()
```

Comment: when I use in_array_command  in blade file show this error.  >in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

Comment: oh now I get you, you need to call toArray(), lists() return collection

Answer (score 2):

Although you have marked the Answer, This is a much simpler approach

```
App\User::pluck('id')->toArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8 this works for me

```
$arr = SomeModel::where("field", value)->get()->toArray();
```