# Getting result from DB by laravel DB class which the each index of array is the result id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Guys I'm trying to get the result form my database by laravel 5.5.
If I run this code:

```
DB::table('comments')->get()
```

It will return an array which contains stdClasses.
Now I want the key(index) of each stdClass in the array be ID of the stdClass.

I just want to know that laravel has this feature ?

**Update:**
This is returned Array for example:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    ....
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    ....
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    ....
                )

        )

)
```

notice above code. I want 7,8,9 to be instead of 0,1,2 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eloquent ORM laravel 5 Get Array of ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308169/eloquent-orm-laravel-5-get-array-of-ids)

Comment: Laravel has all of the features. Laravel be praised.

Comment: @Amarnasan thank u that informed me, but my sentence means suggest the way just for laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck

```
DB::table('comments')->get()->pluck('id');
```

**Edit** It seems you want to key your array by id.

There is this method https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-keyby , 
so it would be something with the looks of

```
DB::table('comments')->get()->keyBy('id')->all();
```

Comment: Just edited my answer, it appears it was miss comunication

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for 2 columns (for example 'title' and 'id'):

```
DB::table('comments')->get()->pluck('title', 'id');
```

tnx Sérgio Reis but you dont need ->all();

just:

```
DB::table('comments')->get()->keyBy('id');
```